# Creating arguments for an ant task with lines from file

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant task, which takes multiple arguments. I would like to pass the arguments loaded from file/property.

I tried the below code, but got error.

```
<loadfile property="file" srcfile="names.properties"/>
<java classname="com.task.MyTask" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <for param="line" list="${file}">
            <arg value="--names"/>
            <arg value="${line}"/>
         </for>
</java>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: please mention the errors you got.

Comment: build.xml:16: java doesn't support the nested "for" element. Is there any other alternate approach for this